# Using word2vec with mixed language data

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I scraped my Facebook chat history and wanted to try out some basic machine learning stuff with word2vec. However, the data has all sorts of stuff - links, emoji, Cyrillic alphabet, etc. Even if I manage to clear some of those, would it be possible to process the Cyrillic alphabet with word2vec?

Comment: Use an aligned [multilingual embedding](http://sebastianruder.com/cross-lingual-embeddings/) if you want to handle Cyrillic languages.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down voted.

Comment: @debzsud I was really confused about that as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word2Vec uses the bag-of-word model as input which means that you can use whatever alphabet. Building a bag of word just consists of attributing one feature per word in the entire dictionary of your corpus. You can do this with a cyrillic alphabet as with other alphabet.